# Changing ItemMeta with BukkitTask

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm not able to change `ItemMeta` on `ItemStack` that's placed on a player inventory via repeating task.
I tried the following:

```
BukkitTask taskTp;
int tempTp = 20;

private void rodarTeleport(final Player player, final ItemStack item) {
    final ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
    final String nome = meta.getDisplayName();

    taskTp = Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimer(plugin, new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (tempTp > 0) {
                tempTp--;
                meta.setDisplayName(nome +" - " + tempTp + "s restantes." );
                item.setItemMeta(meta);
                player.updateInventory();
            }
            else {
                meta.setDisplayName(nome);
                item.setItemMeta(meta);
                player.updateInventory();
                taskTp.cancel();
            }
        }
    }, 20, 20);
}
```

It's supposed to change the display name once every second, but it's not updating it at all.

Comment: I tested out your exact code and it worked. Is the console displaying any errors? Are you sure the item has metadata and a display name? Did you try debugging with print statements?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, so see what happens if you remove the runnable task and just use a random number for `tempTP`... You *shouldn't* get a different result

Answer (score -1):

Before you update the player inventory:

```
p.setItem(slot, item);
```

So you can be sure, that the item is now at the right position.

Comment: Neither updateInventory nor re-setting the item in the slot are necessary in this situation (setting the new item metadata automatically updates the display name). Adding the item again allows the player to dupe it by moving the original item to a different slot.

Comment: You can't say. If the ItemStack is a copy of the item in the players inventory, it doesn't help to update the inventory without outting the new item back to the slot. Please remove the -1 Flag, because you can't say if it is a copy or not